# file_get_content Return something only on certain account but not on some other

Tags: php, request, instagram

Hi So I am setting up a system where you enter an isntagram username and then the website get the informations about this account (username, profilepic, followers and following...)

So i am doing this with simple php code with file_get_content and fetching to get the id of the suer and then go to the info page with this url and the preset instagram info link.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$html =file_get_contents('https://instagram.com/'.$username);

$subData=substr($html, strpos($html, 'window._sharedData'), strpos($html, 
'};'));
$userid=strstr($subData, '"id":"');
$userid=str_replace('"id":"', '', $userid);
$userid=strstr($userid, '"', true);

$userData = 
file_get_contents('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/'.$userid.'/
info/');
$userDecodedData=json_decode($userData);

session_start();

$username = $userDecodedData->user->username;
$profilepicurl = $userDecodedData->user->hd_profile_pic_url_info->url;
$followers = $userDecodedData->user->follower_count;
$following = $userDecodedData->user->following_count;
$bio = $userDecodedData->user->biography;

$_SESSION['scoreinsta'] = $followers - $following;
```

So this works just fine when type my instagram username or my friend's but not when  I try with kylie jenner's username or Instagram's or Ariana Grande, i've tried with cristiano ronaldo account to see if instagram was blocking all the most famous people but it works with his account :/ I'm kinda lost...

```
file_get_contents(https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/12281817/info/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\wamp64\www\Fame\addinsta.php on line 11
```

(error message I get when I trie with Kylie Jenner).

This is the error message but what I dont understand is that you can try the url it gives and it works jsut fine (you can see the info in an array or whathever) but the error message says he cant access it.

Edit: I'm currently trying with every most followed accounts I can and it doesnt work with taylor swift also.

Comment: Instagram may block those popular accounts from automated crawlers.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought at first but the account of Cristiano Ronaldo works and he has even more followers than the blocked ones. Seems a bit random ...

Comment: Maybe the account owner gets to decide. But if your code is the same for all of them, and the ID is correct, what else could it be other than them blocking you?

Comment: Another possibility is a rate limit, if you're doing it too frequently.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah you're probably right, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You lack cookies to be able to retrieve data from the url:
you can try (ex: for case me):

```
    $ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/12281817/info/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authority: i.instagram.com';
$headers[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3';
// $headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: vi-VN,vi;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Cookie: mid=XS3ghgALAAGXu10Eb58jOsW7SAEi; fbm_124024574287414=base_domain=.instagram.com; csrftoken=tNVs4niJr2fLiLh76dPPGJuFaMlihIEd; ds_user_id=3043596499; sessionid=3043596499%3ArcZihGFrIEdqkX%3A6; shbid=14335; shbts=1565197428.8656168; rur=FTW; urlgen=^^^{\"113.177.118.128\":';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: i'm gonna try this but I dont know why it doesnt retrieve data only on certain profile ... But thanks for this solution i'm gonna try it  right away.

Comment: Can you please just quickly explain what all this headers are and do please ?

Comment: Instagram needs to provide you with a cookie to return the data to you. I think it is a measure of their users